# Fourier transform with respect to x with partial y derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

For a function $f(x,y)$ that decays rapidly as $x \rightarrow_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ we define its Fourier transform with respect to $x$ by $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)e^{-ikx}dx$

a) Prove that if $g(x,y)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ then $\tilde{g}(ky)= ik\tilde{f}(k,y)$

b) What is the corresponding result for $h(x,y)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ when transforming with respect to x

I have answer part a by substituting in so I have

$\tilde{g}(k,y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} e^{-ikx}dx$

and then integrated by parts with $u=e^{-ikx}$ and $v=f(x,y)$

However I don't get how to do b) as you are differentiating and integrating with respect to different things.

Comment: Check rules of changing differentiation with integration.

Answer (score 1):

Because the integral converges and nothing else in the integral depends on $y$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} e^{-i k x}  = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: f(x,y) e^{-i k x} = \frac{\partial \hat{f}}{\partial y} $$

Comment: What is $\frac{\partial \hat{f}}{\partial y}$

Comment: The derivative of the FT with respect to $y$.